# Laravel Model reference inside Controller gives error while hosted on Heroku

Tags: laravel, heroku, deployment

I have build a Lingo game in Laravel. The app is hosted on Heroku: https://lingo-hu.herokuapp.com.

Whenever I click the 'Start Game'-button it should send a HTTP-POST-REQUEST to my WordController. After doing so it gives the following response:

```
"message": "Attempt to read property \"word\" on null",
"exception": "ErrorException",
"file": "/app/app/Http/Controllers/WordController.php",
"line": 23,
```

My WordController reference to the 'word'-model:

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use App\word;
    use App\game;
    
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    
    class WordController extends Controller
    {
    }
```

However this action does work on my computer when running Laravel locally, just not on Heroku which I don't understand.

Console error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
app.js:699 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (app.js:699)
    at settle (app.js:960)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (app.js:168)
```

The database is up and running, I used `php artisan migrate` and that's working.

Anyone a suggestion on what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: provide the code that the error is actually referring to ......

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused because the database table where the Word model was referring to was empty. So I imported an export from my MySQL database. Now it works!